# How to Install Pentaho CE 5.0.1

Tags: pentaho

Can anyone tell me how to install pentaho suite CE 5.0.1. I already have the previous version which works fine. I downloaded the new version but then when I try to start the server the cmd just blinks. I assumed that since the environmental variable and setting i have worked for the previous version, they should automatically work for the new one. What am I doing wrong here ? Also the new PRD fails to display the correct formatting (like background coloring) of reports I created with the older version however the colors appear when preview the report. How do I get the new bi server working pls I have searched the internet but cant seem to find a clear cut installation process

Comment: Hi, Can you check your folder permission or set JAVA_HOME path If your previous tomcat running in background on same 8080 port first kill that and then test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that I had a 32 bit java version installed though my OS is 64 bit. I installed a 64 bit version and change the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` accordingly to point to the x64 version and bi-server works fine now.
All's good.

Comment: It's enough if you change the start-pentaho.bat file, in the IF "%BITS%" == "64" branch just copy the line from the 32 bit section.